# Google sheets wildcard isn't working in my formula (FILTER)

Tags: google-sheets

This works: `=FILTER(diseaseR!C3:C, diseaseR!A3:A = "pediatric MSK disease", diseaseR!B3:B = "includes")`

And this works: `=FILTER(diseaseR!C3:C, diseaseR!A3:A = "pediatric GI disease", diseaseR!B3:B = "includes")`

But this doesn't work: `=FILTER(diseaseR!C3:C, diseaseR!A3:A = "pediatric*", diseaseR!B3:B = "includes")`

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=FILTER(diseaseR!C3:C, 
 REGEXMATCH(diseaseR!A3:A, "pediatric"), 
 REGEXMATCH(diseaseR!B3:B, "includes"))
```